# How can I make an excel user defined function (UDF) work in an array function (CSE)?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am using Excel 2010.

I wrote a UDF to create a unique number for each month:
yearmonth = 12*Year(date) + Month(date)

Now I want to use it in a CSE:
{=sum(if(yearmonth('plan'!$j$3:$j$1000)<>yearmonth(A5),0,'plan'!$k$3:$k$1000))}

This renders a #value! error. When I use "Evaluate Formula" the #value! error appears when excel tries to calculate the first array (yearmonth('plan!$j$3:$j$1000)). So it appears the problem is with using my udf in a cse.

The udf works fine on its own (outside the cse). If I remove the udf and replace it with the long form of the equation
{=SUM(IF(12*YEAR('Plan'!$J$3:$J$1000)+MONTH('Plan'!$J$3:$J$1000)<>12*YEAR(A5)+MONTH(A5),0,'Plan'!$K$3:$K$1000))}
that works fine also.

What do I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not an answer to your general question about UDFs and array formulas, but it may help you to get the sum that you want: `TEXT(date, "yyyymm")` can be used in place of your `yearmonth` function.  It evaluates to a string that is, essentially, the textual representation of 100*Year(date) + Month(date).  If you don't expect to deal with large data sets, and you don't expect to be using this spreadsheet in 85 years, you can probably get away with `TEXT(date, "yymm")`.

Comment: Scott, my question, in effect, addressed two issues; UDFs used in array functions and, the unstated issue, compacting formulas so they are more easily understood in 85 years or by the next person to use the tools I create. Your solution addresses the second quite nicely and I am using it until I can figure out the first issue. Thank you for the help.